# Can't use rails http status on grape exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape

I'm new to rails programming and i'm trying to use `rails status code` when raising a grape exception but my tests are failing. I couldn't find any example on grape documentation so this may be impossible.

I want to know if it is possible and if not, why so?

This works:

```
rescue_from Example::IsExampleWorking do |_e|
    error!({ messages: ["Example is not working because it was not found"] }, 404)
end
```

But this does not:

```
rescue_from Example::IsExampleWorking do |_e|
    error!({ messages: ["Example is not working because it was not found"] }, :not_found)
end
```

My test is:

```
it "return a 404 Not Found status" do
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
end
```

edit: guys, I forgot to mention that the error message from he test is

```
undefined method `to_i' for :not_acceptable:Symbol
Did you mean?  to_s
```

But I didn't find any documentation on grape's docs to make sure they accept only integer as second param.

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Can you please also post the code you are testing.

Comment: Yeah. You might create an issue in grape repo with this question. One of the solutions would be to use `Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:not_found]`. I would prefer just a number in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

Grape allows specification of `type` when defining parameters.

```
params do
  # Basic usage: require a parameter of a certain type
  requires :param_name, type: Integer
end
```

See: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/ruby-grape/grape/Grape%2FDSL%2FParameters:requires

Answer (score 0):

Http status code are always integer only. That is the industry standard. You can not change the http status code or send http status code as string.

Find the list of http status codes here. 
https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

And this is not specific to rails or grape or any other framework.